# How to locate source of Error 500 ( Operation successful ) in IIS server with .NET Rest API

Tags: asp.net, api, iis, http-status-code-500

I developed a REST api with .NET framework, and I hosted it in iis server, And it works good but sometimes it returns 500 errors, so I have to restart the api for this error to disappear.I tried many solutions to make the error disappear but no one worked for me. Are there any tools that could help me locate the source of the problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I tried that but the error that I found in trace is 'Operation successful'

Comment: You can post the error log here, it should provide the key error and warning.